# /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1 iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248520/gcc-4-2-failed-with-exit-code-1-iphone)

Any idea why I'm getting this error message?

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

I was trying to integrate MGTwitterEngine and yajl into my project, so followed the instructions over here...

http://damienh.org/2009/06/20/setting-up-mgtwitterengine-with-yajl-106-for-iphone-development/

Managed to get it to compile but it stopped with that error.  Have now removed all the framework references I added to my project, and removed all the MGTwitterEngine classes, basically putting it back to what it was.  Whenever I compile, I still end up with this...

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

If I open other projects, they work fine...

Very strange, any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Check that you don't have any frameworks in your project which don't exist for the iPhone. For example, I've seen a few people add QTKit.framework when they meant to add QuartzCore.framework.

Otherwise, post the actual output from the build command. In the "Build Results" window the error will have a small button to the right for more info.

Comment: I've managed to clear it and now have another problem.

In the Target Info file, it had some strange references to the Library Search Paths.

Problem I have now is I've ended up with 1.0.7 libyajl library whereas MGTwitterEngine has been developed to work with 1.0.6

Nothing is running smoothly today...

Answer (score 1):

in my case it was that i had in two different classes the same @implementation and @interface

like this ->

ViewController2.h:

```
@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController
```

ViewController2.m:

```
@implementation ViewController2
```

ViewController3.h:

```
@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController
```

ViewController3.m:

```
@implementation ViewController2
```

Comment: You've posted this answer several times, without proper formatting. Please format your code snippets and try to add more context to your answers.

Comment: Sorry, i am new to stackoverflow. Because people helped me fixing some problems i thought i can help them as well. I found the same question more times, so i posted it several times. -> in future i will give them a link. Formatting on the way.

Answer (score 0):

I had duplication of the class RssData.h and RssData.m. Removed one of them and it was fixed.