# Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1 iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248520/gcc-4-2-failed-with-exit-code-1-iphone)

Can anybody tell what does this error means?

```
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at these posts: [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248520/gcc-4-2-failed-with-exit-code-1-iphone), [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490847/developer-platforms-iphonesimulator-platform-developer-usr-bin-gcc-4-2-failed-wi), [post3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166408/developer-platforms-iphonesimulator-platform-developer-usr-bin-gcc-4-2-failed-wi)

Does that help?

Comment: Thanx man your post gave me idea and my problem has been solved now...

Answer (score 1):

Me too got the same error and I got solution by doing like this.Take target, Build settings and check for the search paths. Remove unwanted Library search paths.