# Apple LLVM compiler 3.0 Error comes in IPhone Phonegap BarcodeScannerplugin

Tags: iphone, plugins, cordova

I want to run Iphone Phonegap BarcodeScanner plugin in IPAD.  I have gone through the zing document and Barcode read.txt files(git hub) . I did the actions mentioned  in the documents but it will showing     Apple LLVM compiler 3.0 Error   . I have changed 3.0 to 4.2 version also but no change . so can any one guide me .

This the error if put 4.2 version
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

If i changed to 3.0
it shows this error    clang error exit code 1

No i am using Xcode 4.2 version . I have changed all the things mentioned in the above link but it showing the the error  following error Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Comment: it is hard to help you without any output from the compiler

Comment: Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1                  it shows above error(for 3.0 version)                                                   ------........Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1       for 4.2 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this [link](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/BarcodeScanner)

and read this topic"Compile Errors for Automagic Reference Counting (ARC)" in this link

and implement . I have resolve my problem .

Comment: No i am using Xcode 4.2 version . I have changed all the things mentioned in the above link but it showing the the error  following error Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460918/command-developer-platforms-iphonesimulator-platform-developer-usr-bin-gcc-4-2 use this link