# Error Exit code 1

Tags: xcode

I just added a new view controller to my project and now when I attempt to build the project I'm getting this error:

```
 Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Scroll up - the actual error is before the compiler stopping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See these post for reference .. Btw the actual error will be before this line. some file will be missing or duplicating itself.
[post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248520/gcc-4-2-failed-with-exit-code-1-iphone),
[post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490847/developer-platforms-iphonesimulator-platform-developer-usr-bin-gcc-4-2-failed-wi),
[post3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166408/developer-platforms-iphonesimulator-platform-developer-usr-bin-gcc-4-2-failed-wi).