# /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1 error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gcc, simulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1 iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248520/gcc-4-2-failed-with-exit-code-1-iphone)

I am getting the error

```
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

every time I try to run the program on the iPhone device and the Simulator.

I am also seeing this:

```
ld: duplicate symbol .objc_class_name_MainView in /Volumes/Mark's Flash Drive/iFtB/build/iFtB.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iFtB.build/Objects-normal/i386/MainView.o and /Volumes/Mark's Flash Drive/iFtB/build/iFtB.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iFtB.build/Objects-normal/i386/iFtBAppDelegate.o
```

too. Could this be part of the problem?

Thanks in advance,

Mr. Man

Answer (score 11):

It means the `MainView` class is defined twice or more.

Check:

1. If the `MainView` class's `@implementation` appears in any `.h` files. It shouldn't.
2. If there are 2 `MainView` classes define by you and a third-party library. You may need to rename your `MainView` class.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but just wanted to say thanks for this answer. Fixed my problem too. :)

Comment: @sudo: How did u fix this problem?

Comment: @Krishnan:  Yikes, that was a while ago.  Just look to see if you have a duplicate file somewhere.  Search your entire project for the name of the class in question and see if it's duplicated.

Comment: Great! The problem appeared that I added a view class twice (which was inside an another folder).

Answer (score 4):

As KennyTM is correct.

I accidentally imported the .m file instead of the .h an received this lovely error.

Comment: This was also the case with me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem when i add Reliability class to my code.  I already included tree20 to my project which is having reliability class.  So when I add the reliability class again to my class I got the same error.  I removed the Reliability code from my project and it works perfect.