# IPhone : got error when rename the app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

When i rename my app name i got this error while running a app,

Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

How can i solve this?

Comment: for project in inspector i have changed the project name & it automatically Analysis & change the name.

Comment: you can rename from poject in your Xcode or [this link might help you][1]  


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166408/developer-platforms-iphonesimulator-platform-developer-usr-bin-gcc-4-2-failed-wi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renaming the app Name:

Targets-> Select Build-> Search Product Name-> Change value

Answer (score -1):

You can try this in Xcode:

```
menu:project:rename
```