# Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1ld: library not found for -liLibs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am getting Apple Mach-O Linker Id error, while compiling the iphone app.  And getting below error

> Ld
>   "/Users/adminbluepal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tiger-czyksblsmfqdqybamuutemvjbdek/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tiger
>   Dev.app/Tiger Dev" normal i386
>       cd /Users/adminbluepal/Desktop/Dir-Tiger_latest
>       setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
>       setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2
>   -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk
>   -L/Users/adminbluepal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tiger-czyksblsmfqdqybamuutemvjbdek/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/adminbluepal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tiger-czyksblsmfqdqybamuutemvjbdek/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -filelist "/Users/adminbluepal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tiger-czyksblsmfqdqybamuutemvjbdek/Build/Intermediates/Tiger.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tiger.build/Objects-normal/i386/Tiger
>   Dev.LinkFileList" -Xlinker
>   --no-demangle -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -liLibs -framework AVFoundation -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreMedia
>   -framework Foundation -framework GameKit -framework OpenGLES -framework
>   QuartzCore -framework Security
>   -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -lz -o "/Users/adminbluepal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tiger-czyksblsmfqdqybamuutemvjbdek/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tiger
>   Dev.app/Tiger Dev"

```
ld: library not found for -liLibs
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

> Command
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2
>   failed with exit code 1

Please help me out of this

Thank you,
Madan Mohan

Comment: possible duplicate of [gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1 iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248520/gcc-4-2-failed-with-exit-code-1-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday i had this problem.... cleared that error with the help of this answer. it may help you also...

You probably don't have the CoreGraphics.framework added to your frameworks list.

To make sure, click the "Frameworks" folder on Xcode. If the framework isn't listed on the table to the right, you'll need to add it by right-clicking the Frameworks folder, chooseing "Add Existing Framework..." and then choosing it from the list.
Source [stack overflow previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248520/gcc-4-2-failed-with-exit-code-1-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to use the iLibs library (Google says it's something for game development). XCode cannot properly link to it. Try adding their Framework to your project, or read the help docs of the library for help with its setup. Alternatively, see if you can remove the "-liLibs" linker flag in your build settings, if you aren't using the library.