# How to compile Eigen in iPhone

Tags: iphone, c++, compilation, eigen, cross-compiling

I want to compile Eigen and use it in iPhone with NEON features.
How to compile Eigen in iPhone? Do In need to compile for specific ARM chip? And do I need to modify build script?

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since explicit vectorization for ARM NEON is supported out of the box in recent versions of Eigen I'm guessing you shouldn't have to do anything special at all. The section on installation in the manual reads:

> In order to use Eigen, you just need to download and extract Eigen's source code (see the wiki for download instructions). In fact, the header files in the Eigen subdirectory are the only files required to compile programs using Eigen. The header files are the same for all platforms. It is not necessary to use CMake or install anything.

Summary: it's an all-header library. No compilation needed.

Assuming you have the proper toolchain set up you should be good to go. If you're using one of the supported compilers (gcc, I assume) it should auto-detect which optimizations to compile (edit: assuming the right compiler flags, e.g. NEON turned on).

As for how to compile stuff for iPhone, well, on that topic I'm oblivious :D

Comment: It's not that simple - Eigen does various tricks on different architectures to enable vectorization. It's not certain that this tricks will work on iPhone.

Comment: And why not? With a supported compiler (e.g. gcc) and the right compiler flags (-mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp) NEON should be auto-detected and explicit NEON vectorization used. It's in the FAQ: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=FAQ#How_can_I_enable_vectorization.3F

Comment: Thanks guys. I worked on it for several hours and finally get it working. I used xcode 4. Need to use armv7 optimized arch in build setting, other then that I need to set user header search path and compile flag as Staffan said.

Comment: Another thing I can't figure out is that the Eigen header libs have some hearder file without using .h extension. In Xcode 4, I can't using #include them. I modified those file to .h files and it finally works. And I have to define EIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE before include Eigen libs. Other wise it gave me Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1 compile error.

Comment: gcc has no problems including files no matter the extension (example: iostream), so that should be fixable (are the files in your include path?, etC.). EIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE sort of defeats the purpose since you won't get the (explicit) vectorization that way. Maybe you get lucky and the compiler performs some magic for you, who knows :)

Comment: Also, it seems you should be able to get more detailed information on the compilation error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248520/gcc-4-2-failed-with-exit-code-1-iphone